# Подскажите как подключать сторонние библиотеки к C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, библиотеки, mingw

Среда разработки: Visual Studio Code, Компилятор: MinGW GCC G++. Нашёл кучу информации по Microsoft VS но ничего по моему случаю. Я новичок в C++ подскажите, может есть какие нибудь менеджеры пакетов, которые позволяют это делать, или что то подобное. Хотелось бы чтобы было удобно, и не нужно было каждую библиотеку подключать длинными командами каждый раз при сборке и пересборками по часу.

Comment: Менеджер пакетов для mingw называется [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: *"Хотелось бы чтобы было удобно"* - При использовании С++ об этом можете забыть.